# Fetching today's records actually getting yesterdays records in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I used to get today's record from MySQL database. I used this code:

```
$whr_follow = "(DATE(R.reg_time) = Date(NOW()) )" ;
$this->db->where($whr_follow);
```

Today is march 1st, but I get yesterdays. In local server it works fine. 
I tried `select now()` query in phpmyadmin.

In live server it resulted `2019-02-28 23:30:36` but in local server its `2019-03-01 10:59:14`

I tried to change phpmyadmin timezone win phpmyadmin running `set timezone=timezone` (asia/kolkatha) but makes no changes.Any idea?

Comment: I think you forgot to set your local timezone. It's just like this `date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Bangkok");`

Comment: sorry it was included in config php. i m using codeigniter framework

Comment: Can you show your full query?

Comment: Are you loading your config correctly? You can set it on `autoload.php`

Answer (score 1):

change the time zone on your live server, because your live server is late, not your local server.

hope this helps!

Comment: i tried to change mysql time zone by running "SET time_zone = "+05:30";" bt it makes no changes. is there a way to do the same?

Comment: how to change the timezone in cpanel? any suggestions?

Comment: lets try date_default_timezone_set(), follow this documentation and make sure using a right timezone string identifier, or try using "America/Los_Angeles" like on documentation to make sure it work!

Answer (score 1):

first get current date.i hope it will help you.

```
$date = new DateTime("now");

 $curr_date = $date->format('Y-m-d ');

 $this->db->select('*');
 $this->db->from('tablename'); 
 $this->db->where('DATE(Date)',$curr_date);//use date function
 $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
```

Comment: I typed the same answer but your post first. I think it's right  +1 (:

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure both local and live server have the same time zone.

Second, make sure your input and the date format in the DB should be same

```
$current_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('now')) //Current date
```

Make other date format same as well

Answer (score 0):

=>You get Current Date and then change your date Formate `"Y-m-d"` same as a database date format.

```
$date = new DateTime("now");

$currDate = $date->format('Y-m-d ');

 $this->db->select('*');
 $this->db->from('Table Name'); 
 $this->db->where('DATE(Date)',$currDate);
```